# What are all the best practices need to be followed in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I wanted to best practices to be followed if many large group of people writing playbook.

1) Folder structure 
2) where to override variables?
3) Vault
4)Dynamic inventory 
etc

Answer (score 1):

Read this:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html

> Here are some tips for making the most of Ansible and Ansible playbooks.